# Switching Auto layout on results in crashing the application on Mac OSX 10.7.5 only

Tags: cocoa, autoresizingmask, autolayout

Application crashes if I switch on "Use Auto Layout" feature for my xib file.
The error on console is:

"**Assertion failure in -[NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1138.51/Layout.subproj/NSLayoutConstraint.m:596**".

If I disable this feature the application runs smoothly. I tried `[View setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]` also but same result.

Runs fine on Mountain Lion and on some Lion machines.

OS: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5(11G56). Could anybody help me to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it crash on **all** 10.7.5 machines all the time?

Comment: No, It crashes on few of the lion machines and on some machines it works fine.